# Vue js - как программно отрендерить компонент?

Tags: html, vue.js

Есть компонент, который принимает один параметр для отображения. Возникла необходимость отрендерить его не в шаблоне, а в методе (для последующей конкатенации с остальными кусками разметки и вставкой через v-html). Знаю, что выглядит это, мягко говоря, странно, но всё же - как реализовать такое поведение?

Comment: Типа нужно динамически вставлять элемент в разметку?

Comment: Что-то вроде того. Я уже перечитал несколько раз раздел доки о рендер-функциях, но не нашёл или не увидел того, что мне нужно. Я хочу узнать, возможно ли получать в методе одного компонента, в цикле, уже скомпилированную html-разметку другого компонента, и при этом сохранять функциональность и реактивность этого скомпилированного компонента?

Comment: Мне кажется, что это нужно гуглить в сторону миксинов и, возможно, переключения компонентов. Посмотрите, наверняка там можно найти решение всех своих проблем житейских без изобретения чего-то над фреймворком

Comment: Также, возможно, могут подойти слоты. Знать бы что за задачу ты решаешь, может что-то толковое рассказал бы.

Comment: Через v-if нельзя? или вставить как свойство data

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин Спасибо, попробую. Я, на самом деле, такого там нагородил - тонны кода, даже песочницу оформить будет долго (да и стыдно :) ), поэтому и спрашиваю в таком формате.

Comment: @ValeraKvip нет, я точно не об этом)